# AWS S3 file uploading via Postmans and Newman (NOT binary)

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, postman, newman

I'm trying to upload files to AWS S3 using Newman for backend automation tests. 
But I don't how I can do it, because the only working way which I found is using the **binary** body type with selected local fie on my Desktop in the PUT request.

There are two requests for this:

1. The first request gets for us pre-signed URL: 
   [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uahts.png)
2. The second PUT request using for uploading the files:
   [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znO8w.png)

But could you help me: **which decision for Newman?** Because of binary files is not valid in this case.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Newman places any restriction on uploaded files over and above Postman's function. You can upload any kind of file with any kind of content with Postman afaik.